# Displaying content by ID (views.py)

Tags: python, django

I've developed a university system application for practice, and get such problem: I have to display the list of specializations belonging to some chair. And here problem is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chairs/1`, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chairs/2` and etc. are showing all of the specializations like in this [image: this] screenshot . But I want to display them only according to chairs id. Here are my codes:

views.py:

```
def list_of_specialties(request, chair_id):
    chairs = Chair.objects.all()

    if chair_id:
        chair_id = get_object_or_404(Chair, id=chair_id)
        bachelor_sp = Specialty.objects.filter(degree_id=1) 
        master_sp = Specialty.objects.filter(degree_id=2)
        phd_sp = Specialty.objects.filter(degree_id=3) 

    context = {
        'chairs': chairs,
        'chair_id': chair_id,
        'bachelor_sp': bachelor_sp,
        'master_sp': master_sp,
        'phd_sp': phd_sp,
    }
    return render(request, 'specialties.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('chairs', views.chairs, name='chairs'),
    path('chairs/<int:chair_id>', views.list_of_specialties, name='list_of_specialties'),
    path('chairs/<int:chair_id>/<int:specialty_id>', views.list_of_specializations, name='list_of_specializations'),
]
```

models.py:

```
class Chair(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    chairman = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Specialty(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    chair = models.ForeignKey(Chair, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    degree = models.ForeignKey(Degree, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Just filter on the `chair` as well as the `degree`: `Specialty.objects.filter(chair=chair_id, degree_id=1)`. Note you're messing up names here (`chair_id` should not be replaced with a `Chair` instance like you do). And you should not use absolute foreign key values like 1, 2, 3. Fetch the actual `Degree` instance that corresponds to bachelor and filter on that. You should never rely on ids like that.

Comment: @dirkgroten, I just solved it by myself, but thanks a lot again, man !